# Error While trying to send emails with a Spring Boot API : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandler

Tags: java, spring, email

I am trying to send emails through my Spring boot api, i imported the mail starter dependency from maven (I'm sending the whole pom.xml for context)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectColocarUK</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projectColocarUK</name>
    <description>project for Colocar Courier UK</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

then I create my service :

```
import jakarta.mail.MessagingException;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String sender;

    public void sendOrderConfirmationEmail(String recipient, String orderDetails) throws MessagingException {

        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);


        helper.setTo(recipient);
        helper.setSubject("New Order Registered");
        helper.setText("A new order was created, Order Information is : "
                + orderDetails);

        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }

    public void sendOrderChangeEmail(String recipient, String orderDetails) throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

        helper.setTo(recipient);
        helper.setSubject("There was a Change in an Order");
        helper.setText("There was a change in a pending order, New Order information is : "
                + orderDetails);

        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

In my application.properties i configures : spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port, spring.mail.username, spring.mail.password, spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth, spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable, mail.newOrders.destination (email where i want to send the notifications to);

when i call the service :

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<order> create_order(@RequestBody order order){
        order newOrder = order_service.create_order(order);
        try {
            emailService.sendOrderConfirmationEmail(receiverMail, order.getOrderDetails());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error sending confirmation email");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newOrder, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

it returns this error :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandler
```

the curious thing is, if i add the dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

it then returns this :

```
Failed message 1: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.geronimo.mail.handlers.TextHandler cannot be cast to class jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler (org.apache.geronimo.mail.handlers.TextHandler and jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler are in unnamed module of loader 'app')] with root cause

org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.geronimo.mail.handlers.TextHandler cannot be cast to class jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler (org.apache.geronimo.mail.handlers.TextHandler and jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that you have is in mixing `javax.` dependency with `jakarta.` dependency in the project to fix it remove all `javax.` dependency to `jakarta.` because you are using spring boot > 3.x

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

that was moved to `jakarta` from [3.x version](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0).

Instead of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Add it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also a little bit about your `pom.xml` file:

Remove:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And instead of it add next one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also in your code you will have to replace all `javax.` imports to `jakarta.`.

Comment: The version of the validation starter isn't necessary (inherited from the parent), but it's definitely better to use Spring Boot starters as much as possible to prevent version mismatches.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem, i had tried to add the jackarta activation dependency before this, but i got another error (java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.geronimo.mail.handlers.TextHandler cannot be cast to class jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler), I think changing the javax validation also had something to do with it working now, so thank you for that suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Link : https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation/1.2.0?smo=true
```

go to that link add dependency it will work

Comment: Can you add more information for your solution? Like add an example of your solution